# Flatten array in depth one

Tags: crystal-lang

I try to get one depth flatten method

> `[ 1, [2], [[3]] ] => [1, 2, [3]]`
>
> `[ 1, 2, [[3]] ] => [1, 2, [3]]`
>
> `[[1, [[2, 3]]]] => [1, [[2, 3]]]`
>
> `[1, 2] => [1, 2]`

Update my code to

```
def flatten(array)
    result = [] of typeof(array) | typeof(array.first)

    array.each do |item|
      if item.is_a?(Array)
        result = ([] of typeof(item) | typeof(item.first)) + result
        result.concat(item)
      else
        result << item
      end
    end

    result
  end
```

But flatten([1, 2]) Failed to raise an exception https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3p6h

Look https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be safe you need the union of the array type and its element types:

```
def unwrap(array)
  result = [] of typeof(array)|typeof(array.first)
  array.each do |item|
    if item.is_a?(Array)
      result.concat item
    else
      result << item
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: It feels like this ought to be possible with `flat_map`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `unwrap([[1, [[2, 3]]]]) # [1, [[2, 3]]]` https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3p6g not work on this :(

Comment: For completeness: this is a compiler bug and tracked in https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5805